# Pebble - Detect Shake Gesture

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble

How can I detect shake gestures from Pebble?

I just want to show up a text-layer when shaking the pebble...

They added a new API in SDK 2.0:

https://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___accelerometer_service.html

http://developer.getpebble.com/2/guides/accelerometer.html

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need control over the strength of the shake, you can use [accel_tap_service_subscribe](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___accelerometer_service.html#ga2e90659ec79d5c57a3a28b0127595f3d).

Comment: Actually this API does give you the axis on which the shake was performed.

Comment: Whoops, corrected! Strength is still out of your control, though.